# How to count time while phone is shaking in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, motion

How to count time while phone is shaking in swift?
 want to get time measurement how long phone is shaking.

```
var timer = Timer()
var timeLeft = 0

override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if(motion == .motionShake){
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(onTimerFires), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if(motion != .motionShake){
        print("MotionEnded")
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

The timer is working endlessly. How to stop the timer when shaking stop...​

Answer (score 1):

To measure the `timeInterval` between the shaking `start time` and `end time` using,

```
var startDate: Date?

override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if(motion == .motionShake){
        self.startDate = Date()
    }
}

override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if(motion != .motionShake){
        if let startDate = self.startDate {
            let timeInterval = Date().timeIntervalSince(startDate)
            print(timeInterval)
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I've stored the `Date` instance at which `motion begins` and when the `motion ends` `timeInterval` is calculated using the `current date` and the `stored date`.

Comment: `UIEvent` has a `timestamp` field, you can use that and save yourself the calls to `Date`

Answer (score 0):

Tested on a real device :

```
  var startShaking = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

  override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .motionShake {
      startShaking = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    }
  }

  override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .motionShake {
      let shakingTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startShaking
      print("shaking for \(shakingTime) seconds")
    }
  }
```

Comment: It goes in the first "if" , but "else" is not working.

Comment: Please see update, I tested it on a real device and it seems to works properly

Answer (score 0):

Try below code : Here the startDate is the timestamp when the shaking is started.

```
override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        startDate = Date()
        print("Motion begins")
    }

    override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("Motion ends")
        let endDate = Date()
        let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second, .nanosecond], from: startDate!, to: endDate)
        let formattedString = String(format: "%02ld %02ld %02ld %02ld", difference.hour!, difference.minute!, difference.second!, difference.nanosecond!)
        print(formattedString)
    }
```

The output will print the time difference in hour, minutes, seconds and nano seconds.

Hope this helps.